# Using CSS animation onClick() in React

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, react-hooks, css-animations

I want to create an animated toggleable sidebar.

I defined animations in css and add them via conditional operator based on React useState value.
Clicks on BLUE div change the useState value.
Here is a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/polished-dew-jsjybz?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx)

```
function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const show = () => {
    setVisible(true);
  };

  const hide = () => {
    setVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="red-box"></div>
        <div className={"blue-box " + (visible ? "expandin" : "expandout")}>
          <div
            onClick={visible ? hide : show}
            className={"" + (visible ? "slidein" : "slideout")}
          >
            BLUE
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The problem is animation triggers only once on page load. Subsequent button clicks instantly move the elements instead of smoothly moving them over time.

I need to make it to not animate itself on page load and play correct animation after click (forward or reverse).
I found out that I can't just swap animation classes and it has to be reset first somehow in order to be animated again but I couldn't figure out way to do this myself.

How to do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add class to the element to trigger the animation, then remove it after the animation completes

```
.toggle-button {
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.toggle-button.animate {
  animation: slidein 0.5s forwards;
}


function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [animationActive, setAnimationActive] = useState(false);

  const show = () => {
    setVisible(true);
    setAnimationActive(true);
  };

  const hide = () => {
    setVisible(false);
    setAnimationActive(true);
  };

  const onAnimationEnd = () => {
    setAnimationActive(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="red-box"></div>
        <div className={"blue-box " + (visible ? "expandin" : "expandout")}>
          <div
            onClick={visible ? hide : show}
            className={"toggle-button " + (animationActive ? "animate" : "")}
            onAnimationEnd={onAnimationEnd}
          >
            BLUE
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I managed to make it work as I needed. One problem is, since I'm removing animation classes, it didn't preserve changed state with 
animation: forwards, so I removed it and added extra check if it's open and append class with styles for open and closed states. Check codesandbox for details.